# Piping from grep to awk not working

Tags: bash, grep, rhel, awk, tail

I am trying to `grep` the ongoing `tail` of file log and get the `n`th word from a line. Example file:

```
$ cat > test.txt <<EOL
Beam goes blah
John goes hey
Beam goes what?
John goes forget it
Beam goes okay
Beam goes bye
EOL
^C
```

Now if I do a `tail`:

```
$ tail -f test.txt
Beam goes blah
John goes hey
Beam goes what?
John goes forget it
Beam goes okay
Beam goes bye
^C
```

If I `grep` that `tail`:

```
$ tail -f test.txt | grep Beam
Beam goes blah
Beam goes what?
Beam goes okay
Beam goes bye
^C
```

But if I `awk` that `grep`:

```
$ tail -f test.txt | grep Beam | awk '{print $3}'
```

Nothing no matter how long I wait. I suspect it's something to do with the way the stream works.

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's probably output buffering from grep.  you can disable that with `grep --line-buffered`.

But you don't need to pipe output from grep into awk.  awk can do regexp pattern matching all by itself.

`tail -f test.txt | awk '/Beam/ {print $3}'`

Comment: Could you help to comment why `tail -f test.txt | awk -f CERTAINLIB.AWK -e '/Beam/ {print $3}'` does not work ?

Answer (score 13):

Using `tail -f test.txt | awk '/Beam/{print $3}'` works for me. As well as using `tail -f test.txt | grep --line-buffered Beam | awk '{print $3}'` (gnu grep).

The issue here is if `awk` received the data line-by-line or as one larger data block.  The GNU version of grep sends output in larger blocks since it is more efficient, but `awk` needs to read line-by-line in order to output line-by-line.

Put this way: `grep` will only send data when the buffer is filled, awk is waiting for that buffer to be filled, so it's sending out nothing.

Answer (score 4):

See the `--line-buffered` option of `grep`.