# Regex that would grep numbers after specific string

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

So I have a line:

```
ID: 54376
```

Can you help me make a regex that would only return numbers without "ID:"?

**NOTE:** This string is in a file.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
grep -oP '(?<=ID: )[0-9]+' file
```

or:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /ID:.*?(\d+)/' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't need all numbers from a file a need only a number that occurs after ID:

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Note that `-o` and `-P` are GNU extensions to `grep`. `-o` works on the BSD's as well. PCRE support with `-P` is not always compiled in either.

Answer (score 7):

There are *many* ways of doing this. For example:

1. Use GNU `grep` with recent PCREs and match the numbers after `ID:` :

   ```
   grep -oP 'ID:\s*\K\d+' file
   ```
2. Use `awk` and simply print the last field of all lines that start with `ID:`

   ```
   awk '/^ID:/{print $NF}' file
   ```

   That will also print fields that are not numbers though, to get numbers only, and only in the second field, use

   ```
   awk '($1=="ID:" && $2~/^[0-9]+$/){print $2}' file
   ```
3. Use GNU grep with Extended Regular Expressions and parse it twice:

   ```
   grep -Eo '^ID: *[0-9]+' file | grep -o '[0-9]*'
   ```

Comment: Thanks! What `\K` is doing in first example?

Comment: @rnd_d it's a Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) construct which means "ignore anything matched up to this point". It is used like a lookbehind, it let's me use `-o` to print only the matched portion but also discard things I'm not interested in. Compare `echo "foobar" | grep -oP "foobar"` and `echo "foobar" | grep -oP 'foo\Kbar'`

Answer (score 4):

Use `egrep` with `-o` or `grep` with `-Eo` option to get only the matched segment. Use `[0-9]` as regex to get just numbers:

```
grep -Eo [0-9]+ filename
```

Comment: The OP needs it to match only after a specific string. See the question's title.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n '/ID: 54376/,${s/[^ 0-9]*//g;/./p}'
```

That will print only all numbers and spaces occurring after `ID: 54376` in any file input.

I've just updated the above a little to make it a little faster with `*` and not to `p`rint blank lines after removing the non-{numeric,space} characters.

It addresses lines from regex `/ID: 54376/` `,`through the `$`last and on them `s///`removes all or any `*`characters `^`not `[^ 0-9]*` then `p`rints `/`any`/` line with a `.`character remaining.

#### DEMO:

```
{
echo line 
printf 'ID: 54376\nno_nums_or_spaces\n'
printf '%s @nd 0th3r char@cter$ %s\n' $(seq 10)
echo 'ID: 54376'
} | sed -n '/ID 54376/,${s/[^ 0-9]*//g;/./p}'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
 54376
1  03  2
3  03  4
5  03  6
7  03  8
9  03  10
 54376
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
{
    echo "ID: 1"
    echo "Line doesn't start with ID: "
    echo "ID: Non-numbers"
    echo "ID: 4"
} | sed -n '/^ID: [0-9][0-9]*$/s/ID: //p'
```

The `-n` is "don't print anything by default", the `/^ID: [0-9][0-9]*$/` is "for lines matching this regex" (starts with "ID: ", then 1 or more digits, then end of line), and the `s/ID: //p` is of the form `s/pattern/repl/flags` - `s` means we're doing a substitute, to replace the pattern `"ID: "` with replacement text `""` (empty string) using the `p` flag, which means "print this line after doing the substitution".

Output:

```
1
4
```

Comment: It won't work if the ID present in the center of a line.

Comment: Nor should it, based on my reading of the question.  And not trying to prematurely handle that case makes the code simpler and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Another GNU sed command,

```
sed -nr '/ID: [0-9]+/ s/.*ID: +([0-9]+).*/\1/p' file
```

It prints any number after `ID:`

Comment: You really don't need the `+`. If the difference between one character and 3 characters is your script may not work in all `sed`s you should probably do: `sed -n '/ID: \([0-9][0-9]*\).*/{s//\1/;s/.*[^0-9]//;/./p}'`. Your answer also misses the first `ID: [0-9]` on a line containing two occurrences of `ID: [0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep + awk :

```
  grep "^ID" your_file | awk {'print $2'}
```

Bonus : easy to read :)

Comment: You don't need `grep` if you're using `awk`.  `awk '/^ID/ { print $2 }'` does the same thing, and avoids [grep line-buffering issues](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46720/7696).  It's also pretty much the same as one of the solutions in  @terdon's answer.