# Grep with spaces suddenly doesn't work

Tags: grep, tail, rsyslog

When performing a `grep` like:

```
$ tail -f apilog_2014.07.09.log | grep "HELLO" | grep "99999"
```

I get the desired output:

```
12:22:35 server apache2:  HELLO FRIEND 99999
12:22:35 server apache2:  HELLO FRIEND 99999
12:22:35 server apache2:  HELLO FRIEND 99999
```

However if I do:

```
$ tail -f apilog_2014.07.09.log | grep "HELLO FRIEND" | grep "99999"
```

I don't get anything.

My locale settings are all set to `en_US.utf8` and I've tested with `[[:space:]]` and with `\s`. No results. The file itself is `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` (checked with `file -bi apilog_2014.07.09.log`).

The files themselves are written with `rsyslog`, if that is any type of hint. Using `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS`.

Is there anything I'm missing?

As requested:

```
$ grep "HELLO" apilog_2014.07.09.log | od -c
0000000   1   4   :   2   7   :   0   0       s   o   f   i   a       c
0000020   a   r   l   o   s   :           A   P   I   L   O   G       H
0000040   E   L   L   O       F   R   I   E   N   D       t   e   s   t
0000060   i   n   g  \n   1   4   :   3   1   :   4   5       s   o   f
0000100   i   a       c   a   r   l   o   s   :           A   P   I   L
0000120   O   G       H   E   L   L   O       F   R   I   E   N   D
0000140   t   e   s   t   i   n   g       6   3   9   0   3  \n
0000156
```

**UPDATE 14 Jul 2014**

Answer here: [Grep with spaces suddenly doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141507/grep-with-spaces-suddenly-doesnt-work#answers-header)

Related question (same solution): [Piping from grep to awk not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46715/piping-from-grep-to-awk-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: There is probably a strange character between `HELLO` and `FRIEND`. Please run `grep HELLO apilog_2014.07.09.log | od -c` and post the output here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, please post the output of the exact command I asked for.

Comment: Hey trendon, I've posed this on a gist for easier reading, running the command as you typed it

https://gist.github.com/charlydagos/de3470c65dd99d04cbc0

Comment: I would try: `grep -e 'HELLO.*FRIEND' tst.txt`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you must have `grep` aliased to `grep --color=always`. That's not a very good idea, you might want to change that to `grep --color=auto` (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138923/22222)). Anyway, could you please post the output of `\grep HELLO apilog_2014.07.09.log | od -c` instead? That way the color codes of the matched portion won't confuse things (the `\ ` will bypass any aliases and run the command directly).

Comment: Does this work? `grep -E "HELLO[^\S+]FRIEND" file`

Comment: Hey terdon, here's the gist with two outputs, one like you said and, since you're right I do have grep aliased to `--color=always` (changed that now to `--color=auto`), I tried with with `auto` again. 

Hopefully it yields some help :) https://gist.github.com/charlydagos/ae38cbe30577225188c5

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. If you recall at the beginning of the question, I'm doing primarily `tail -f`. I was mistaken when I said that there was no output, I left a console running and eventually (10 minutes later), there was output. It's explained with further detail here

http://www.ateamsystems.com/tech-blog/grep-output-is-delayed-or-no-output-when-piping-or-using-multiple-grep-calls-with-pipes/

Why the space character affects the time between outputs is still a mystery, but following the issue in that link solved it.

Basically I edited my `.bashrc`

`alias grep="grep --color=auto --line-buffered"`

And now I get the desired output.

Comment: Great. My answer was incorrect. Removed.